# A Company of Thirteen

Tags: pattern, word-property

These thirteen English words share a hidden property:

**cold, laughter, unblock, word, kill, witch, even, now, warm, oil, talking, potted, corn**

The list is not complete, there are other words with the same property, most don't fit the pattern though. What is this property?

Comment: Would `quad` and `port` be welcome to join the crowd?

Comment: [Googling the keywords](https://www.google.com/search?q=cold+laughter+unblock+word+kill+witch+even+now+warm+oil+talking+potted+corn&oq=cold+laughter+unblock+word+kill+witch+even+now+warm+oil+talking+potted+corn&aqs=chrome..69i57.760j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) takes you to the answer: http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/october42012/index.html

Comment: I misunderstood "there are other words with the same property, most don't fit the pattern though" to mean that the other words with the same property don't fit the pattern (implying that there's some second property of the words you picked).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Adding S as the first letter gives new words.

Comment: Well, that didn't even last five minutes. Good job, I'll accept it as answer once the system lets me.

Comment: @Moghwyn *She's quick!*