# Another Company of Thirteen

Tags: pattern, word-property

These thirteen English words share a hidden property:

### GULLS, FUSION, BOMB, MILLS, DON, FUR, CHAIN, MOCHA, HYMN, WOLFS, MUNCH, PINY, WITS

The list is not complete; there are other words with the same property, but most English words don't fit the pattern. Can you name two other words of at least three letters with the same property?

---

This puzzle was inspired by [Moghwyn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9910/moghwyn)'s puzzle ***[A Company of Thirteen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10527/a-company-of-thirteen)***.

*Note: The solution to this puzzle is not related to that solution.  The only similarity is that they both contain a group of thirteen words.*

Comment: And no, the answer is not that none of the words contain an `E`

Comment: Did you mean "WOLVES"?

Comment: @FollowMyProposals:  No, `WOLFS` as in, "My brother wolfs down his food so fast, you can hardly even see it!"

Comment: "DON MILLS" is a community in Toronto. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: @JoeZ. There's also a Mills bomb and a fusion bomb ... but we're looking for a *property* of these words, not links between them!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possible other words include:

> AILS, ALUM, BOG, BOY, BUFF, BULLS, BUM, DUG, FILLS, FIN, GOLEM, LION, MIX, SUE, SYNC, WILY, WOMBS

as well as many other more obscure ones.

The property that all of the words have is that

> if you increment each letter by 6 (so A→G and Y→E) the resulting string is also an English word. This is also known as a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Comment: That's amazing.