# Find the relation between these words?

Tags: letter-sequence

You are in an island looking for a chest and finally you have found it. Unfortunately there is a embedded lock on the chest which has a note on it:

```
Wolfs are Curly
Oafs are Ugly
Wiles are Corky
Muffs are Sally

Wombs are ?
```

This lock is a letter lock showing "AAAAA". So how can I open it?

Comment: I know it would wreck the puzzle but it should be 'wolves'. I know, sorry I was being pedantic there

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11062

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be

> Rot 6, yielding the answer "cushy".
>  The various "rot" ciphers "rotate" the alphabet by the given number of letters. This is described fully [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). For solvers, just google "rot n".

Comment: Could you expand on what "Rot 6" means to us uninitiated?

Comment: @user1717828 rotational alphabet cipher. Look up rot13. Every letter is replaced by the one six letters ahead.

Comment: @user1717828 Expanded with an explanation. It's a good thing to know about.