# What is a Peruvian Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word has a certain property, I call it a ***Peruvian Word™***.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

| Peruvian Word™ | Non-Peruvian Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| COVER | COAT |
| BANGED | SLAMMED |
| BEND | TWIST |
| FAILED | PASSED |
| ENDER | FINISHER |
| CAPPED | HATTED |
| BEAKER | FLASK |
| BANKED | RAMPED |
| BOT* | ROBOT |
| BARING | SHOWING |

* represents Extra-Peruvian Word™.

Here is a CSV version:

```
Peruvian Word™, Non-Peruvian Word™  
COVER,COAT
BANGED,SLAMMED
BEND,TWIST
FAILED,PASSED
ENDER,FINISHER
CAPPED,HATTED
BEAKER,FLASK
BANKED,RAMPED
BOT*,ROBOT
BARING,SHOWING
```

Comment: ...I had this *exact same* property in mind for a future puzzle, though I was going to call it a Christmas Word.

Comment: Interesting. Rather in the spirit of [the very first "word-property" puzzle on this site](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10527/a-company-of-thirteen).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think a Peruvian word is one for which

> You can add a letter L to make another word

The examples are

> COVER → CLOVER
>  BANGED → BANGLED
>  BEND → BLEND
>  FAILED → FLAILED
>  ENDER → LENDER
>  CAPPED → CLAPPED
>  BEAKER → BLEAKER
>  BANKED → BLANKED
>  BOT → BLOT and BOLT  (extra Peruvian)
>  BARING → BLARING
>
>  And they may be called Peruvian because Lima is the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) for the letter 'L'

Comment: Wow, Coatl is so embedded in my brain as a word from way too many games that I never would have come up with that. Congratulations.

Comment: @Sconibulus Where is "Coatl"?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος adding an L to the end of COAT, the first Non-Peruvian word

Comment: @Sconibulus Hate to break it on you, but [here](https://www.google.com#q=coatl) it says that **coatl** is not an English word.

Answer (score 4):

Credit to Tom for discovering the salient property. Perhaps such words are called Peruvian because

> "lama" is Peruvian thanks to "llama".